# what is happening when a host receives a datagram with its MAC address as a destination but different destination IP

Tags: ip, tcp, ip-address

In a specific network say the host receives this datagram what is happening ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

- If the host is a router (a router is a host), then this perfectly normal, and the router will hapilly forward the packet according to its routing table (dropping it if it has no route for the destination)
- otherwise the host will simply drop the packet.

Note that all modern operating systems also have routing capabilities and the packet may be passed on a Virtual Machine for example.

Comment: Modern OS if the is DOS, Windows, MAC, GNU/Linux and UNIX then its a YES,they have had routing capabilities for the last ~30 years.

Comment: Neither (MS)DOS, Windows 3/9x/ME, nor Mac OS classic (pre OS X) were ever capable of routing, only by running additional software.